# Get profile photos in different sizes

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

This is how i get the profile photo.

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/picture?width=150&height=150&redirect=false&access_token='.$access_token; 
$fb_photos = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
```

I want to get more than one user's photo.
I can loop and get the photos and i can change the width and height values.

How do i do this in a best way without looping? If i loop everytime, I guess it will make lot of calls to bring the static url of the photo.

Can i get those 5 to 10 profile photos in one call? I need the size to be different!

Comment: Why don't you just request the largest photo and resize it yourself?

Comment: Facebook resizes the photo in good way. src_big is not that much big anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
fql?q=SELECT pid,src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (123,456,789)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Batch Request

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/17/batch-requests-in-graph-api/

Build up your query into a json array, and then submit it in one request.

Comment: Can i convert an array to json array?

Comment: You can use php's json_encode function to convert a php array into a json array.